# firefox sync's bookmarks then ignores homepage setting

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

I have no idea what could have caused it, only thing I have recently installed is filezilla via source forge, however I dont believe the source forge installer can cause this,

however for some reason, when my firefox opens, it automatically opens the webiste (which fails to load) [http://www.%snf%.com/](http://www.%25snf%25.com/), I assume it is www.snf.com which a search engine which closed down

if i delete and resync my profile, i select everything except "bookmarks", and all is well, the moment I select bookmarks and sync it, after next open, it defaults to that webpage

there are no bookmarks mentioning the website, in advanced options it show the default homepage as the firefox default page

anyone have a suggestion besides using a brand new profile/copying everything except the bookmarks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found that the solution to this problem is fairly simple. Just check the shortcut to your firefox browser - it should read something like **"C:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %SNF%** when you open its properties. Just remove the trailing **%SNF%**, and save the shortcut - your problem will get fixed.

**Alternatively**: In case you do not want to meddle with your existing shortcuts, you can go to the folder which contains firefox, locate the file firefox.exe - right click on it and select"Create Shortcut" from the popup menu. Use the newly created shortcut to open Firefox now onwards, and the problem with snf will no longer be there.

Comment: i thank you, good sir, however I had a virus(es) scurrying around in the path "C:/Program Data/MachineHelper" and "C:/Program Data/MachineHelpers" which I assume may have infected/hacked my firefox account, among which also edited the mozzila launch options, but I eventually got rid of it, but thank you for your research